# JQuery field containing single quote breaks my code

Tags: jquery, powerschool

I can't figure out how to escape this particular '. I have the following code:

```
//Insert Home Room Teacher
$j("tr:contains('Home Room')").after('<tr><td class="bold">Home Room Teacher</td><td><input type="text" name="[01]home_room_teacher" value="" size="25"></td></tr>');
```

**[01]home_room_teacher** is a field that contains the student's home room teacher's last name. One of our teachers last name is O'Shea. As is, the code works for every other teacher fine. If I load a student who has him for their home room, the ' in his last name breaks the script and none of it loads (there are multiple things in the page fragment).

If I do **name="\[01]home_room_teacher\"**, the page loads properly but the field is blank. I've also tried to edit the actual value in the field to show O\'Shea, but that doesn't work either.

Please help.

EDIT: Here is the full code that is being run:

```
<script>
$j(document).ready(function() {

//Insert Counselor
$j("tr:contains('Family rep')").before('<tr><td class="bold">Counselor</td><td><input type="text" name="[01]Counselor" value="" size="25"></td></tr>');
//Insert Home Room Teacher
$j("tr:contains('Home Room')").after('<tr><td class="bold">Home Room Teacher</td><td><input type="text" name="[01]home_room_teacher\" value="" size="25"></td></tr>');
//Insert Teacher Rec
$j("tr:contains('School Entry Grade Level')").after('<tr><td class="bold">Teacher Recs Visible</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="[01]RecDisplay" value="1"></td></tr>');

//Hide Rows
$j("tr:contains('Lunch'), tr:contains('District'), tr:contains('Current'), tr:contains('Phone'), tr:contains('Student'), tr:contains('Track')").css("display", "none");

//Swap TR with TR
$j("tr:contains('Locker Combination')").insertAfter($j("tr:contains('Locker Number')"));

//Alternate Color Rows
$j("td:even").css("background-color", "transparent");
$j("td:odd").css("background-color", "transparent");
$j("tr:even").css("background-color", "#D7EBF4");
$j("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
});
</script>
```

Comment: you could use a special character like % in place of the ' like O%Shea and find and replace it in the html after your .after.  Probably not the best solution though

Answer (score 0):

**Try using the following javascript, this should work.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  teacher = "O'Shea";
  $("#show").html('<tr><td class="bold">Home Room Teacher</td><td><input type="text" name=' + teacher + ' value=' + teacher + ' size="25"></td></tr>');
  $('#print').text($('#show').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="show">

</table>
<div id="print">
</div>
```

And you can directly replace the variable `teacher` with : `[01]home_room_teacher`

Comment: Unfortunately teacher pulls from a field within the student table, so I can't hard code O'Shea as that would not display properly for students that don't have him for home room.

Comment: @Dfoles : You don't need to hard-code O'Shea, I meant you can directly replace the variable `teacher` with the your `[01]home_room_teacher` variable.

Comment: I tried that, as well as putting it in quotes and ("") etc to no avail. I get "undefined" if it works

Comment: @Dfoles : You tried using it as : name=' + [01]home_room_teacher + '

Comment: I'll have to try that when I get back to a computer.

Comment: So would I be able to add that to the .after (.after.html())?

Comment: @Dfoles : Yes you'd be able to add it to your code, basically instead of  `$j("tr:contains('Home Room')").after('<tr><td class="bold">Home Room Teacher</td><td><input type="text" name="[01]home_room_teacher" value="" size="25"></td></tr>');`, just write : `$j("tr:contains('Home Room')").after('<tr><td class="bold">Home Room Teacher</td><td><input type="text" name='+[01]home_room_teacher+' value="" size="25"></td></tr>');
` , and the code should work fine then.

Comment: Still no go :( I even tried doing name="'+[01]home_room_teacher+'"